# Jenkins build Docker raise error Unrecognized field "ExecDriver"

Tags: jenkins, docker

I'm integrating Docker with Jenkins, but the build is showing the following error

```
VERSIONS
 - Jenkins version 1.555
 - Docker  version 0.9.0

Jenkins Plugins
 - Mercurial (to pull code from bitbucket)
 - Docker (docker-plugin)
 - docker-build-step

[Docker] INFO: created container id e463f956d2d4.... (from image my-base)
FATAL: org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "ExecDriver"
docker-build-step
```

Comment: I fix it with downgrade Docker to 0.8.1

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the Docker plugin for Jenkins is very strict about what it expects, and when Docker 0.9 returns an `ExecDriver` value (for instance, in `docker inspect`) it gets confused.

The easiest fix is, as you did, roll back to 0.8; but it would be better to fix the Jenkins module; either by using semver (Docker API is versioned) or by making the code accept the `ExecDriver` attribute optionally.